# No Route Matches [POST] Bloc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

Alright I know there's a million posts on this but I can't seem to find a way to fix mine. I'm new to rails, just starting on my first solo-project after going through a guided one over at bloc.

I'm hitting this error:

## No route matches [POST] "/registered_applications/new"

---

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :registered_applications 

  devise_for :users

  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'

  root :to => 'welcome#index'
end
```

---

Here's the form. When submit is clicked we hit the error:

> I was trying `<%= form_for @application do |f| %>` but I was getting an error so I changed over to this. Any suggestions here  would be appreciated as well.

```
<h3 class="roboto">Register a new application</h3>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>Application Registration Guidelines:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Applications must be named.</li>
      <li>You must provide a URL.</li>
      <li>You must be signed in to add an application to your account.</li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 app-reg">
    <%= form_for(:application) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Application name" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :URL %>
        <%= f.text_field :URL, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Application URL" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Here is my controller:

> Definitely a work in progress

```
class RegisteredApplicationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @applications = Application.all
  end

  def new
    @application = Application.new 
  end

  def show
    @application = Application.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @application = Application.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create 
    @application = Application.new(application_params)
    if @application.save
      flash[:notice] = "Application was saved successfully."
      redirect_to @application
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error creating the application. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end
end

private

def application_params
  params.require(:application).permit(:name, :URL)
end
```

---

If you feel the need to see it, here is the Application Model:

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

---

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change resources :registered_applications to resources :applications in routes.rb, as Application is your model and applications is name of the table which is treated as resources.

You are getting the error because there is no resource or table named registered_applications, as you have named your table as applications and model as Application.

Comment: there is no any restrictions in naming of controllers and matched models

Comment: Yeah I'm still going to rename the models and controllers to something else, `Application` is just asking for trouble. @RoaringStones

Answer (score 0):

From your code I assume you get that error when hitting post button in the Application creation form, right? So you should definetely use `@application` instead of `:application` as *for* model in form generation. As you wrote you have tried that but something went wrong: it would help to get the problem solved if you specify what exactly did.

`resources registered_application` does not create for you route for POST action to registered_applications/new. only POST to registered_applications

UPDATE:
also I wouldn't recommend you to name models, class variables the other important variables/models likely to be named: like you `Application` class. That can be a root for painful strange errors